# Recommendation to learn css

Tags: website-design, resource-recommendations, css

How would you recommend to proceed to learn css?

Is there a great book, or online tutorial?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is the best repository i know
[css 101](http://www.jasonbartholme.com/101-css-resources-to-add-to-your-toolbelt-of-awesomeness/)

and some thing that bother most of us is [floating](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/)

as far as books are concern i love "Eric Meyer" way of doing stuff, but some other worth mentioning books i read

- CSS Cookbook by Christopher Schmitt
- Core CSS by Keith Schengili-Roberts

hope that will help you getting startted

cheers

Answer (score 3):

These are some online tutorials that might help you a lot:

- [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css)
- [CSS Tricks](http://www.css-tricks.com)

More web-based tutorials that aid you in learning CSS.

- [456 Berea Street CSS Category.](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/categories/css/)
- [W3C CSS Tutorials and e-Books](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/learning)
- [A List Apart CSS Category](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/code/css/)

Answer (score 1):

I like [Stylin' with CSS,](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321525566) and SAMS's [Teach Yourself HTML & CSS in 24 Hours](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672330970) is also good.

I did take a CSS course, but they taught out of the Lynda books.

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of CSS: The Missing Manual. It allows you to either start from the beginning and read through to the end, or open the index and answer specific questions on what you're doing.

The best way to learn anything is to do it. Make some web pages with bad CSS ("Why is my text always falling off the side?!?") and then look up the solutions (I like the W3Schools pages a lot, too). There's nothing like working through some bad CSS to give you confidence in working with CSS.

I also agree with the sketchbook - I keep one at home and one at the office. If you know what you want your page to "look like" it will become much easier to write CSS that matches your layout.

Answer (score 1):

also, try CSS3: Visual QuickStart Guide (5th Edition)